# MySQL: How much mySQL-Query-Requests are allowed

Tags: php, mysql, request

where can i set the amount of the mySQL-Query for a time-period? In my php.ini? What is it called?
I have a project, where I have mysql-requests. Local its no problem, I send over 1500 Requests and it goes very fast. But on the Server it stocks after about 400-500 Requests and thwors this Error in theFirebug:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
Service Unavailable
The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later!
```

I have no entries in my error-log. 
Maybe I have to set up the request of mysql? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of per-account parameters that can be used for rate limiting:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'francis'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
    ->          MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
    ->          MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
    ->          MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;
```

See [Setting Account Resource Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-resources.html)

Comment: So there is no way to change it over the infos in phpinfo()?

Comment: It's not a PHP limit, it's in MySQL.